# RequiredFieldValidator error message persists even after closing ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

please help me friend,
i create modalpopupextender, and i use asp requirefieldvalidator on textbox inside the mpe.. the rfv is already appear when i click button submit. but the problem comes when i click the cancel button.. the panel will close. but when i click link mpe again the error message still appear. and this is my code :

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeSignUp"
    runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopupSignUp"
    TargetControlID="lnkButtonSignUp"
    CancelControlID="btnCancelSignUp"
    OnCancelScript="DoCancel()" 
    DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
 </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopupSignUp" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupSignUp" Style="display: none">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="twitterStyleTextbox" plceholder="Username" /> 
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtUsername" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false" /> <br />
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function DoCancel() {
     $get('<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>').value = "";
     $get('<%=txtPassword.ClientID%>').value = "";
     $get('<%=txtUsername.ClientID%>').value = "";
     $get('<%=txtPasswordSignUp.ClientID%>').value = "";
     $get('<%=txtConfirmPasswordSignUp.ClientID%>').value = "";
     $get('<%=txtEmailSignUp.ClientID%>').value = "";
}
</script>
```

code behind :

```
Protected Sub btnSignUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSignUp.Click

    mpeSignUp.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mark can u help me this

Comment: Does your modalpopupextender and the panel inside an updatepanel?

Comment: @jomsk1e what should i do?

Comment: First you need to wrap your aspx codes inside updatepanel.

Comment: can u give me example on code joms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already found the answer thx anyway  @jomsk1e.

i added this code on js :

```
document.getElementById('<%=rfvtxtUsername.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('<%=rfvtxtPasswordSignUp.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('<%=rfvtxtEmailSignUp.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an updatepanel in your aspx you should try to use one and try triggering with asynpostbacktrigger:

Example not tested:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" CssClass="popup"  runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeSignUp"
            runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopupSignUp"
            TargetControlID="lnkButtonSignUp"
            CancelControlID="btnCancelSignUp"
            OnCancelScript="DoCancel()" 
            DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
         </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopupSignUp" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupSignUp" Style="display: none">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="twitterStyleTextbox" plceholder="Username" /> 
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtUsername" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false" /> <br />

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCancelSignUp" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

hope this helps!

Comment: i got this error :
An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: Are you sure modal and panel that it extends are on the same updatepanel?